# Connecting a Windows Docker Container to a Local PostgreSQL Database

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, dockerfile, windows-container

I'm working on a project where I need to run a Python application in a Windows Docker container. The application connects to a PostgreSQL database that I have running on my local Windows machine. I'm facing issues with setting up the connection between the Docker container and the local database.

My setup:

I have a Windows Docker container where I run my Python application.
I have PostgreSQL installed and running on my local Windows machine.
The Python application needs to connect to the local PostgreSQL database.

The issues I'm encountering include:

```
    Error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\webapp\app.py", line 15, in <module>
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**db_params)

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused 
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

connection to server at "`localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused`
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

How to configure the Docker container so it can reach the local PostgreSQL database on my Windows machine.

How do I open port for Postgresql inside the container

How to ensure the PostgreSQL database allows connections from the Docker container.

How to modify my Python application code to connect to the local PostgreSQL database.

I'd appreciate any guidance or best practices on configuring the Windows Docker container, PostgreSQL, and my Python application to enable successful database connections in this setup.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above error by matching the port numbers of python app file and the dockerfile and used network as 'nat'.

Thanks!